# Pytorch: Need help implementing a custom sliding window

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, convolution

Lets say I have two matrices A and B, both are 10x10.
Now I want a sliding window, 3x3 to go through A and B and:

1. calculate the following result:

[image]

2. then take this result matrix, sum it up, and save it at location *e* inside of a new matrix.

Comment: Some code and attempted solutions would be welcome.

Comment: Are you applying a fixed filter across A and B separately, or is the filter a positionally-dependent 3x3 window _of_ B?

Answer (score 2):

Given you are applying a weighted sum (i.e. a convolution), your kernel is equivalent to the following:

[image]

Which can be straightforwardly implemented with `torch.nn.functional.conv2d`:

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F

kernel = torch.Tensor([[-1,-2,-3],
                       [-4,sum([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]), -6],
                       [-7,-8,-9]])
kernel = kernel.reshape(1,1,3,3)

A = torch.randn(1,5,5)
B = torch.randn(1,5,5)
inputs = torch.stack([A,B])
F.conv2d(inputs, kernel, padding=1)
```